# Cannot purchase gems on one of my device on Clash of Clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have Clash of clans linked to two devices, my phone and my Nexus tablet. I noticed since I did that, I can only purchase gems on my tablet. I cannot purchase gems from my phone. Anyway to fix this being that Im usually on my phone.

Comment: Do you get any error when you are trying to purchase gems? We need more info to help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on IOS be sure to have in app purchases enabled in settings. if you are on Android or blackberry or other devices im not sure how it works but it might be the same